# Creating elements and storing location in realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently making a small web app that creates and stores notes with the location of where you clicked to create the note in a realtime database. I'm having an issue finding a way to reference the objects to update their content after creating the object (with an xPos and yPos) on clicking somewhere within window.

This function happens after clicking somewhere on the screen. It creates an object holding the xPosition and yPosition of where the user clicked, as well as toggling a form that allows a user to input their note.

```
function createXY(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var form = document.getElementsByClassName("form")[0];
    form.classList.toggle("invisible");
    form.style.position = "absolute";
    form.style.top = `${y}px`;
    form.style.left = `${x}px`;
    console.log(`${x}, ${y}`)

    firebase.database().ref("messages").push().set({
        "xPos": x,   
        "yPos": y,
        "sender": "",
        "seed": "",
    })
}
```

I want to reference the object created on this click and update the sender name and seed (note) after a user submits the form. What would be the way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `push()`, Firebase generates a reference with anew unique ID. To be able to add values to that node, you'll need to somehow remember the unique ID.

```
const newRef = firebase.database().ref("messages").push()
newRef.set({
    "xPos": x,   
    "yPos": y,
    "sender": "",
    "seed": "",
})
const newKey = newRef.key; // <-- This is the value that you need to know
```

Where to keep this value varies quite a bit, but most common is to associate the key with the UI elements when you **render** the snapshots on an `on()`/`once()` callback.

```
firebase.database().ref("messages").once("value").then((messagesSnapshot) => {
  messagesSnapshot.forEach((messageSnapshot) => {
    const messageKey = messageSnapshot.key;
    const message = messageSnapshot.val();

    // TODO: create a UI element for the message, and store messageKey in
    //       a non-visible attribute, so you can use it later.
  })
})
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to be updating the UI real time? Is this because of using once.then? rather than on()

Comment: That's correct. If you want the UI to be updated when the database is updated, you'll need to use `on()` instead of `once()`. The rest of the code can remain unchanged.

Comment: A new issue seems to be forming with on() – where everytime I click, it's redrawing all the previous UI elements.

Comment: That's precisely what `on("value"` does. The `messagesSnapshot` will always contain the snapshot of all data at `/messages` and not just the changes. If you want to not show items in the UI double, you can for example clear the inner HTML of the element just before `messagesSnapshot.forEach`. Note though that the main point of my question is before the last code fragment: you'll need to store and track the push ID to be able to use it elsewhere.